# Can't find processing toolbox

Tags: qgis

Where can I find or enable the processing toolbox in QGIS 2.18? Doesn't seem to be an option in the "View" drop menu, and the help file doesn't have anything about how to get it to display

I attached a screenshot of what QGIS looks like to me, maybe it's there somewhere and I'm missing it?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to activate Processing plugin. Go to `Plugins -> Search: Processing -> Activate` You will see Processing menu in QGIS.

Comment: Notice that the option to activate is a check box located next to the processing plugin in the most recent version of QGIS.  There was not an activate button or a right click menu that would have been a more obvious option for me, but I found the toggle box and was able to get the processing toolbox to show up.