# Fill sink problem in deliniation

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

Why doesn't the Fill Sink algorithm appear in the toolbar? How can I make it appear? my qgis is 3.34 version

Comment: Have you tried searching in the Toolbox Ctrl+Alt+T?

Comment: If toolbox is not available: go to the plugins menu and activate (or deactivate and reactivate) the Processing plugin. Happens sometimes that QGIS doesn't activate it properly. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/281818/88814